# How to create a .desktop file that launchs 2 programs at the same time?

Tags: .desktop

I am trying to make a `.desktop` file that launches more than one app.
This are the commands I tried:

```
Exec=appcmd & appcmd
Exec=appcmd AND appcmd
Exec=appcmd && appcmd
```

Comment: ...Since the command to start an application is a command... For two applications, you'd need the first option in the answer.

Comment: There is however a downside to your approach: better not make multiple `.deskop` files run the same application in their "native" command (from the first `Exec=line`. It can cause `WM_CLASS` clashes in launcher icons.